# CVC4: How to get proper unsat core?

Tags: c++, cvc4

Using this code:

```
#include <cvc4/cvc4.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace CVC4;

int main() {
  ExprManager em;
  SmtEngine smt(&em);
  smt.setOption("produce-unsat-cores","true");

  Type boolean_type = em.booleanType();

  Expr p = em.mkVar("p", boolean_type);
  Expr q = em.mkVar("q", boolean_type);
  Expr r = em.mkVar("r", boolean_type);
  Expr s = em.mkVar("s", boolean_type);
  Expr t = em.mkVar("t", boolean_type);

  Expr pq = em.mkVar("pq", boolean_type);
  Expr qr = em.mkVar("qr", boolean_type);
  Expr rs = em.mkVar("rs", boolean_type);
  Expr st = em.mkVar("st", boolean_type);
  Expr nqs = em.mkVar("nqs", boolean_type);

  smt.assertFormula(em.mkExpr(kind::IMPLIES, pq, em.mkExpr(kind::IMPLIES, p, q)),false);
  smt.assertFormula(em.mkExpr(kind::IMPLIES, qr, em.mkExpr(kind::IMPLIES, q, r)),false);
  smt.assertFormula(em.mkExpr(kind::IMPLIES, rs, em.mkExpr(kind::IMPLIES, r, s)),false);
  smt.assertFormula(em.mkExpr(kind::IMPLIES, st, em.mkExpr(kind::IMPLIES, s, t)),false);
  smt.assertFormula(em.mkExpr(kind::IMPLIES, nqs, em.mkExpr(kind::NOT, em.mkExpr(kind::IMPLIES, q, s))),false);

  smt.assertFormula(pq,true);
  smt.assertFormula(qr,true);
  smt.assertFormula(rs,true);
  smt.assertFormula(st,true);
  smt.assertFormula(nqs,true);

  Result result = smt.checkSat();
  enum Result::Sat sat_result = result.isSat();
  if (sat_result == Result::SAT) {
    printf("sat\n");
  } else if (sat_result == Result::UNSAT) {
    printf("unsat (");
    UnsatCore unsat_core = smt.getUnsatCore();
    std::vector<Expr>::const_iterator it = unsat_core.begin();
    std::vector<Expr>::const_iterator it_end = unsat_core.end();
    for (; it != it_end; ++it) {
      printf("%s ", Expr(*it).toString().c_str());
    }
    printf(")\n");
  } else {
    printf("unknown\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following response:

```
unsat (qr rs nqs qr => (q => r) rs => (r => s) nqs => NOT(q => s) )
```

But I would expect something like:

```
unsat (qr rs nqs )
```

I assumed, that the parameter `inUnsatCore` of `SmtEngine.assertFormula` would direct the assertions in that way somehow. But it does not.

What is the correct way of asserting formulas and asking for an unsat core, if not like shown above?

Using a cvc4 version with the tag 1.5 from github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qr rs nqs` is not an unsat core per se (it is trivially satisfiable by setting all three variables to true). It seems like you are trying to achieve something similar to named assertions in SMT-LIB v2. When using `(get-unsat-core)` in SMT-LIB v2, only named assertions in the unsat core are printed.

Your example could be translated as follows:

```
(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)
(declare-fun p () Bool)
(declare-fun q () Bool)
(declare-fun r () Bool)
(declare-fun s () Bool)
(declare-fun t () Bool)
(declare-fun pq () Bool)
(declare-fun qr () Bool)
(declare-fun rs () Bool)
(declare-fun st () Bool)
(declare-fun nqs () Bool)
(assert (implies pq (implies p q)))
(assert (implies qr (implies q r)))
(assert (implies rs (implies r s)))
(assert (implies st (implies s t)))
(assert (implies nqs (not (implies q s))))
(assert (! pq :named _pq))
(assert (! qr :named _qr))
(assert (! rs :named _rs))
(assert (! st :named _st))
(assert (! nqs :named _nqs))
(check-sat)
(get-unsat-core)
```

CVC4's output on this example:

```
unsat
(
_nqs
_rs
_qr
)
```

The way this works internally is that CVC4 keeps track of named assertions and only prints those out while skipping unnamed ones. You could do the same in your code by only printing members of the unsat core if they belong to your set  of relevant assertions (`pq`, `qr`, `rs`, `st`, `nqs`).

`inUnsatCore` has no effect when `produce-unsat-cores` is `true` as far as I can tell. I've added an item for improving that documentation to our maintenance list.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That nearly matches what we are looking for, but not exactly.

Comment: Assume that a number of formulas are asserted on the solver stack, some of which define activation literals. Those formulas have the semantics of an implication of the form act_i => body_i, but let's assume that they cannot be identified syntactically.

Comment: Now we would like to get an UNSAT-core (modulo all assertions on the stack) for a subset S of the set of all activation literals {act_1, act_2, ..., act_n}.

Comment: In principal, this could be achieved by asserting each activation literal from S and checking satisfiablity, afterwards. If the result is UNSAT, we would like to obtain an UNSAT core w.r.t. S, i.e. a (hopefully small) subset of the activation literals in S that is unsatisfiable (modulo the remaining assertions) in itself.

Comment: This should be similar to the new commands "check-sat-assuming" and "get-unsat-assumptions" that are defined in version 2.5 of the SMTLib standard.

Comment: Oh, I see. There is actually an open issue for that: https://github.com/CVC4/CVC4/issues/880 . I'll bring it up at our CVC4 meeting this week.

Comment: Would be great to see this in version 1.6 of CVC4.